# How does Javascript react to errors?

Tags: javascript

I have been quite curious about how javascript reacts to errors(like ReferenceError, for example). When it encounters a runtime error, it seems to return from the function that it is called in which, in turn, fails the function it was called in.

Does it consequently fail all the functions in the frame stack? 
(This is more of a question out of academic curiosity. Hope somebody can explain it to me?)

Thanks!

Comment: This chapter from Eloquent JavaScript might interest you: [Error Handling](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter5.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript exception handling is much the same as other languages' error handling - it will `throw` an error up the call stack until handled by the `catch` of a `try` block. If there is no try/catch, then the current execution will stop.

All the function calls below the `catch` will be exited - they won't return anything, and the following lines of code will not be executed.

Comment: You can use window.onerror event to get a handle on any error which is  not caught. (Note: I am not sure about browsers other than IE)

Answer (score 1):

It continues up the call stack until it reaches a a `try`...`catch` block.

You can see a simple example [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWHEU/).

Comment: Yes and it ultimately fails if a try catch block isn't found. And it fails silently if you don't have a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It returns an Object of the error, and like most Objects, it has has methods and properties

```
try {
    a/1;
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err.name) //ReferenceError
    console.log(err.message); //a is not defined
    console.log(err.constructor); //ReferenceError() { [native code] }
    console.log(err.toString()); //ReferenceError: a is not defined
    console.log(err.stack) 
    /*
      ReferenceError: a is not defined
      at errCatch (<anonymous>:3:11)
      at <anonymous>:1:11
    */
}
```

note, console.log(Object) is the same as Object.toString().
Hope it helps.